# VB Script to auto download and Install Windows Updates from Microsoft

Tags: windows-update

i need to build a script for automate check, download, and unstall windows updates.

i got this VB script at Microsoft site:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wua_sdk/searching--downloading--and-installing-updates?redirectedfrom=MSDN

but when running it ask the user permission ([Y\N]) for various actions .

what do i need to change for it to auto choose 'yes'.

the script comments mentioned this, but i dont know how and what to change on it :

> /Automate: Don't prompt the user for various actions
> '             Default: Prompt the user

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

, try whit this command in PowerShell (Right Admin)

Get-WindowsUpdate

Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll –AutoReboot

If you would not like a reboot to start (so as not to interrupt the production workflow), you can run the following cmdlet:

Get-WUInstall -AcceptAll –IgnoreReboot